# Why would a plastic rod be inserted into ground?

Tags: electrical

I found this in a rental unit and was wondering is there a good reason for this plastic rod to be there:

[image]

Better photo (seems like a Lego part):

[image]

Comment: Note that it could very well be a Lego piece, especially if the previous tenants had children...

Answer (score 6):

Depends on how one defines "good reason"... Anyway, it's definitely a Lego axle. For comparison here's a photo of a similar part from BrickLink. I can't think of any good reason to *leave* the part there, but I can think of good reasons to remove it.

[image: BrickLink part 3705 Lego Technic axle]

Comment: Yup, I think it Lego too. That looks exactly like the picture in the question

Answer (score 1):

That's possibly a left over piece from a splitter. Like a 6-way or 3-way splitter. [image]

Probably broke off when moving out. Or it's just a piece of Lego.

Comment: I was thinking of a child proof outlet cover that plugs in.